# Hide bubble in Amcharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Is there anyway to hide bubble in bubble chart of Amcharts. I have a requirement where I need to hide bubble on click on a button. I checked the documentation, where I couldn't able to find anything.

can anyone guide me how to do that

Comment: Could you add a picture of the bubble? I'm wondering if you mean balloon, which would be something like https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmBalloon#enabled

Comment: balloon is something which looks like tooltip. But if you check with bubblecharts in amcharts, each point will say as bubble which i refer it as bubble. sorry if i have confused you